# How to read props inside a socket.io callback?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

When I try to read my props inside a socket callback function, it throws an error :

```
componentWillMount(){

    console.log(this.props.username); // works
    this.props.socket.on('question', function(){
      console.log(this.props.username); //prints Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
      }
    });
  }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `function()` call changes the context and `this` is no longer pointing to the component's instance, hence `this.props` is `undefined`. You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which would have `this` as the component's instance.

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.socket.on('question', () => { // arrow function
    console.log(this.props.username); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the context of the socket functions since so that you can access the props from the context of the React component otherwise `this` inside the `socket.on` function will refer to its own context rather than the React Component

```
this.props.socket.on('question', function(){
  console.log(this.props.username); 
  }.bind(this)
});
```

or

```
this.props.socket.on('question', () => {
  console.log(this.props.username); 
  }
});
```